# how to disbled lunch time 1:00 pm to 2:00pm in ej2-angular-schedule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to disable 1 to 2 clock. The user does not add a schedule between this time.
Schedule show like below image how can be disabled selected time block. Please help me. thanks in advance

[image]

schedule.html

```
<ejs-schedule width='100%' height='650px' locale='de' [selectedDate]='selectedDate' [eventSettings]='eventSettings'>
    <e-views>
        <e-view option="TimelineDay"></e-view>
        <e-view option="Month"></e-view>
        <e-view option="Day"></e-view> 
        <e-view option="Week"></e-view>
    </e-views>
</ejs-schedule>
```

schedule.ts

```
// more imports
import { L10n, loadCldr, setCulture, setCurrencyCode } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { EventSettingsModel } from '@syncfusion/ej2-schedule';

export class SchedulePage implements OnInit {
  public data: Object[];
  public selectedDate;
  // public eventSettings;
  public eventSettings: EventSettingsModel;
  ngOnInit() {

    this.selectedDate = new Date(2019, 11, 1); //  .toISOString();

    this.data = [{
      Id: 1,
      Subject: 'Explosion of Betelgeuse Star',
      StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 9, 30),
      EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 11, 0),
      AirlineId: 1
    }, {
      Id: 2,
      Subject: 'Thule Air Crash Report',
      StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 12, 0),
      EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 14, 0),
      AirlineId: 3
    }, {
      Id: 3,
      Subject: 'Blue Moon Eclipse',
      StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 3, 9, 30),
      EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 3, 11, 0),
      AirlineId: 2
    }, {
      Id: 4,
      Subject: 'Meteor Showers in 2019',
      StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 4, 13, 0),
      EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 4, 14, 30),
      AirlineId: 1
    }];
    this.eventSettings = {dataSource : this.data };
    // this.eventSettings = EventSettingsModel = { dataSource: scheduleData };
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you... tried anything?

Comment: No. I don't know how to disable

Comment: @VijayPrajapati Please accept the answer if it helped you and resolved your query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add break time you need to explicitly block setting **isBlock** field to **true** within the eventSettings and assigned altogether with the events **dataSource**.
You can refer this [here](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/?_ga=2.62526124.10754710.1583989291-575928286.1583989291#/material/schedule/block-events).

In your case, you have to explicitly add following against every AirlineId.

```
{
              Id: 6,
              Subject: 'Break',
              StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 13, 0),
              EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 14, 0),
              RecurrenceRule: 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;',
              IsBlock: true,
              AirlineId: 2
}
```

+You can write a dynamic function which would push element in this.data for every add schedule with its AirlineId, you can [refer](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/schedule/timeline-resource) this for more information. It is very general answer I hope atleast you will get lead to your solution.

```
this.data = [{
          Id: 1,
          Subject: 'Explosion of Betelgeuse Star',
          StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 9, 30),
          EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 11, 0),
          AirlineId: 1
        }, {
          Id: 2,
          Subject: 'Thule Air Crash Report',
          StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 10, 0),
          EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 2, 13, 0),
          AirlineId: 3
        }, {
          Id: 3,
          Subject: 'Blue Moon Eclipse',
          StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 3, 9, 30),
          EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 3, 11, 0),
          AirlineId: 2
        }, {
          Id: 4,
          Subject: 'Meteor Showers in 2019',
          StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 4, 15, 0),
          EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 4, 16, 30),
          AirlineId: 1
        }, {
          Id: 5,
          Subject: 'Break',
          StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 13, 0),
          EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 14, 0),
          RecurrenceRule: 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;',
          IsBlock: true,
          AirlineId: 1
      }, {
          Id: 6,
          Subject: 'Break',
          StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 13, 0),
          EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 14, 0),
          RecurrenceRule: 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;',
          IsBlock: true,
          AirlineId: 2
      }, {
          Id: 7,
          Subject: 'Break',
          StartTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 13, 0),
          EndTime: new Date(2019, 11, 1, 14, 0),
          RecurrenceRule: 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;',
          IsBlock: true,
          AirlineId: 3
      }];
```